# NoClassDefFoundError for jersey RESTful client in websphere 7.0

Tags: rest, jersey, websphere-7

I am getting the following error for an application that is being deployed to a WebSphere 7.0 environment.

```
servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet action in application foo. Exception created : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.ClientFilter
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
```

Now I currently have this application working in an alternative WebSphere 7.0 environment, but I can't get it to work in the one I need it to.

I have set  the webcontainer custom property.
Name: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFiltersCompatibility
Value: true

I have added the jersey jar(jersey-bundle-1.10.jar) to the class path.
I have added the jar to the lib directory on the WebServer.

For some reason it can't resolve this class, and I know it works in another environment.  Is there some trick to getting the RESTful client working on a server that has never ran Jersey before.